# How to use Feed API and send direct messages to users?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We are in demand of this two API (refer below). Is there any update on the below APIs would be available in near future date ?

1. Post to Activity Feed API (Preview) Send an activity feed notification

   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=63725
2. Provide a Teams API To send direct messages to users

https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38224390-provide-a-teams-api-to-send-direct-messages-to-use

Comment: @nick-kramer-msft, Would be helpful if we get this APIs. Currently in order to achieve above use case we have found out two ways which seems to be complex. One is by Proactive Bot Services and another is by using Power Automate "Post your own adaptive card as the Flow bot to a user"

Comment: These API's are something we are working on but we cannot give you an ETA on when this will be available. Thanks!!

Comment: This can be closed as "recommendations or external resources".

Comment: @Halfer -  let me modify my question. Don't close it

Comment: I am not sure how this question can be rescued. It's asking if a specific API will support features in the future, and is essentially a feature request. The only folks who can answer such queries are the company themselves, and thus it is not a generally answerable question. It would be better to ask this on the tech support forums from Microsoft themselves.